# Integral solutions to $20^m-10m^2+1=19^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Find postive integral solutions of the equation $20^m-10m^2+1=19^n$.

My solution,

1. Using modulo  $10$, I got the information that $n$ is even.
2. Using modulo $19$, I got the information that $m$ should be $19k+2$ or $19k-2$.
3. Using modulo $20$, I got the information that $m$ is even.

By observation $(m,n) =(2,2)$. But how to arrive at a solution and show that only $(2,2)$ is the solution and no other solution exists.

Comment: What do you mean "by observation $(m,n)=(2,2)$ ? That doesn't follow from your statements 1,2,3. What other steps did you do to get $(2,2)$ ?

Comment: One could prove that for $k>1$, $19^{2k}<20^{2k}-40k^2+1<19^{2k+2}$

Comment: What do you mean by Integral solutions? Integers?

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect in right part.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Note that in OP's question the powers on $20$ and $19$ are denoted by different letters $m,n.$ But you use $2k$ for both. Why?

Comment: For $k>1$: $19^{2k}<20^{2k}-40k^2+1=19^{2l}\Rightarrow l>k$ , where $k=m/2$, $l=n/2$.

Comment: by observation i meant i satisfied the least even integers.

Comment: yes by intergal solutions i meant integer solutions

Comment: @Ivan i dont understand your inequality. can u elaborate?

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are even, so $m=2k$, $n=2l$, then $400^k-40k^2+1=361^l$. It's easy to see that $k=1,l=1$ is solution. For $k>1$: $400^k-361^k > 40k^2-1$ (one could easy to prove with derivatives), then $361^l > 361^k \Rightarrow l > k$.

Comment: I believe, using $l>k$ is wrong way, because there are no symmetric upper limitation for $l$.

Comment: Brute force reveals that for another solution , we must have $m>10^5$ which convinces me that there is no other solution, but of course this is no proof. Maybe some specialist can solve this completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that
$$20^m-10m^2+1=19^n.$$
Reducing mod $3$ and $5$ shows that $m$ and $n$ are even, say $m=2M$ and $n=2N$. Then
$$10m^2-1=20^m-19^n=(20^M+19^N)(20^M-19^N).$$
This shows that $10m^2-1$ is divisible by $20^M+19^N$. In particular
$$20^M<20^M+19^N<10m^2-1=40M^2-1.$$
This shows that $M\leq1$, and hence $m=2$ and $n=2$.

Comment: This is the way to go, +1.

Comment: Very nice! Another way to look at this is that $20^m-19^n=10m^2-1$ is the nonzero difference of two squares-because $m,n$ even, and also is positive as well. So this gives $20^m-19^n \ge 20^{m/2} \le 10m^2-1$. The set of positive integers $m$ satisfying $20^{m/2} \le 10m^2-1$ is bounded indeed. And then go from there.